# What does put-call parity imply about option premiums?

Tags: options, arbitrage, soft-question

We know that $$C-P = PV(F_{0,T}-K)$$

When we create a synthetic forward, we buy call and sell a put at the same strike price $K$. When we buy the call why do we assume the premium is positive? When we sell the put, why do we assume the premium is negative?

Comment: You can accept one of the answers if you are satisfied by it :-)

Answer (score 6):

To see the connection between **put-call parity and option price** you should read this highly insightful paper by Espen Gaarder Haug & Nassim Nicholas Taleb:

> [Option traders use (very) sophisticated heuristics, never the Black–
>   Scholes–Merton formula](http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1012075)

It shows how you can heuristically derive option pricing formulas by adapting the tails and skewness by varying the standard deviation of a Gaussian - and then remove the risk parameter by using put-call parity.

Both authors are well known in the Quant-Community, they both have an academic as well as a practical background as traders.

Answer (score 5):

Both premiums are actually always positive by definition.  The difference will be positive when the forward price exceeds the strike and vice versa.